# Flutter indentation on new line in ListBody

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListBody which has a `Text` element and then a `String` which is returned by an API.

Such as..

```
Destination: $destination

Destination: London
```

However, if it is longer is spills over as such

```
Destination: London Paddington
Station
```

How is best to ensure that if the text is long enough to require a new line it is indented with the beginning on the `String` (i.e. The 'L' in 'London' is in-line)

```
Destination: London Paddington
             Station
```

```
ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                
                RichText (
              text: TextSpan( 
              children: <TextSpan> [
              TextSpan(text: "\t\tDestination        ", style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontFamily: 'DMSans'
               )
              ),
              TextSpan(text: "$destination", 
              style: TextStyle( 
              fontSize: 18 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, 
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'DMSans'
               )
              ),
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use a RichText ?
If it was only to render the "$destination" value in bold, it's a little bit overkill, and the following solution may be easier to implement.

```
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "Destination",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
                        fontFamily: 'DMSans'),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "London Paddington Station",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'DMSans'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
```

And the rendering will look like this
[image]

Comment: RichText was for editing other text in the ```ListBody``` and to call the API ```var's``` with ```$```. Is this able to work in RichText/ ListBody? I need them both to post the API data in the List format? Thank you

Comment: A ```ListBody``` is basically a ```Column``` in a ```SingleChildScrollView```, so it'll work with your ```ListBody``` if you wanna keep it. In my example you should be able to replace the ```Text``` in the ```Flexible``` by a ```RichText``` and a ```TextSpan``` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is simply to display the text as a row of two elements, with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

Like so:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Text(
      'Destination: ',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
        fontFamily: 'DMSans',
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'London Paddington Station',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontFamily: 'DMSans',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Note that it's important to wrap the long text in an `Expanded` widget - Otherwise, the text will simply overflow past the edge of the widget, rather than wrapping.

You can see a working example here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=80d0a8514577a65874c0e0ff7f2cb79c

Comment: Is this able to work in RichText/ ListBody? I need them both to post the API data in the List format? Thank you

Comment: It will work in a vertically arranged ListView, as long as there's a size constraint on the width of the list. If the list is horizontal, then you'll need to wrap the `Row` with a SizedBox so that the `Expanded` knows how much space it can take

Comment: As for RichText, I don't believe you can achieve this effect with a single RichText widget. You can use two separate RichTexts though, in place of the `Text` widgets above

Comment: The issue is my second ```Text``` is not a String but a ```$var``` which has a pre set value dependant on API result. Switching Text for RichText throws errors when I change the data type

Comment: What error is that? The variable retrieved from your API has to be converted to a `String` in order to be displayed, regardless of what type of widget you use to display the value. Also, you can convert any value to a string using `myValue.toString()`